# Need help in reducing Replication lag in Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, master-slave, postgresql-10

I have 4 servers, lets say A, B, C, D & E. 
In which A is master and rest all are Slaves.

We used to write on server A and the data will replcated to all. Everything is working fine except Replication lag.

All slaves are our Read nodes.

Sometimes there would be Replication Lag of 5 minutes between master & slave node.

We are using 10.3 version of Postgres.

How can i solve this Replication log issue?

Comment: How do you replicate? WAL shipping or streaming replication?

Comment: Logical Streaming.

Comment: ["Logical replication"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) is something entirely different than ["streaming replication"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION)

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: Well, which replication type **do** you use?

Comment: Logical Replication